# How to inject Illuminate Collections helper functions from laravel into Symfony

Tags: laravel, symfony

I'm using Illuminate Collections outside of Lavarel, in a Symfony project.  What's the best way to inject the helper functions (like collect(), from helpers.php) into a Symfony project?

Injecting it in Kernel.php doesn't seem right.  I'm thinking I could add the function with a use statement, like with Symfony's string component:

```php
use function Symfony\Component\String\u;
```

But I can't find where.

Some functions, like map, can be accessed from a class, e.g. Arr::map(), and maybe collect() that option as well.

I'm new to Illuminate Collections, but so far it seems great. I know the helper functions are built into the laravel framework, but now that the collections library exists independently I'm looking for the proper way to integrate it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried installing via composer `composer require illuminate/collections`? Then you can try and inject it where you need it. Or you could use the [ArrayCollection](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/stable/index.html) that is built into Symfony.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use Illuminate Collection helpers, you have to require  the file `helper.php` in your autoload

The right way to do it, is to add it in your composer.json [`autoload` section](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) :

```json
      "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "vendor/illuminate/collections/helpers.php"
        ]
```

This will require the file in the `vendor/autoload.php` file.

This is how `Laravel\Framework` is doing [the trick](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/composer.json#L122).

Comment: Thanks.  I wish those same functions were available to inject in a class via a use statement.  Adding those functions to global namespace seems wrong, but I guess it makes sense for Laravel.

Comment: You can't `use` thoses helpers since there is no namespace in the `helper.php`, but i'm not a huge fan of exposing global functions like that too :/ If you want to control the dependency, maybe you could just c/c the `helpers.php` and add your own namespace. I personnaly have a `lib` namespace, at the same level of `src`, to build small project scoped libraries and sometimes to extends external ones.